# TypeScript: Interface or type for one of constants or string

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-types

I'm using TypeScript to develop my application. I'm trying to create an interface (or type) that is one of several constants, or a random string.

Pseudo code to describe what I'm trying to build:

`contants.ts`:

```
export const ERROR_A = "Error A";
export const ERROR_B = "Error B";
export const ERROR_C = "Error C";
```

`types.ts`:

```
type SWITCH_ERROR = ERROR_A | ERROR_B | ERROR_C | string
```

I know this way every string can be an error. The reason why I want to do it like this, is so that the codebase can be easily maintained and every known error has it's type. The error will later get handled in a switch statement like this:

`switchExample.ts`:

```
export const someFunc(error: SwitchError): void => {
  switch(error) {
    case ERROR_A:
      // Do something
    // ... continue for each error.
    default:
      // Here the plain string should be handled.
  }
}
```

The problem is I tried doing it like this:

```
import { ERROR_A } from "./some/Path";

export type SwitchError = ERROR_A;
```

But this throws the error:

```
[ts] Cannot find name 'ERROR_A'.
```

What am I doing wrong? How would one design something like this in TypeScript? Or is this bad design? If yes how else could I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is because you have only defined `ERROR_A` as a value but you are trying to use it as a type.  (The error message is unhelpful; I recently filed [an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27630) to improve it.)  To define each name as both a value and a type, you could use the following in `constants.ts`:

```
export const ERROR_A = "Error A";
export type ERROR_A = typeof ERROR_A;
export const ERROR_B = "Error B";
export type ERROR_B = typeof ERROR_B;
export const ERROR_C = "Error C";
export type ERROR_C = typeof ERROR_C;
```

Hayden Hall's suggestion to use an enum is also good, since enum members are automatically defined as both names and types.  But you could avoid all of this and just write `type SWITCH_ERROR = string`; it's equivalent to `type SWITCH_ERROR = ERROR_A | ERROR_B | ERROR_C | string` when `ERROR_A`, `ERROR_B`, and `ERROR_C` are specific strings.

Comment: First of all, great issue! I hope this gets fixed. You might want to add this question as further evidence in your thread. Secondly, thank you for your help. As I commented on [Hayden's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52830151/typescript-interface-or-type-for-one-of-constants-or-string/52831838#52831838), the switch case doesn't catch the enum for some reason. So I guess there is no great way to solve this using TypeScript. And I just might use string and constants just like in regular JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

Something like the following should solve the problem (assuming your error is a string):

```
enum Errors {
    ERROR_A = 'Error A',
    ERROR_B = 'Error B',
    ERROR_C = 'Error C',
}

function handleError(error: string) : void {
  switch(error) {
    case Errors.ERROR_A:
      // Handle ERROR_A
    case Errors.ERROR_B:
      // Handle ERROR_B
    case Errors.ERROR_C:
      // Handle ERROR_C
    default:
      // Handle all other errors...
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and it does not work. The error cases just fall through and the default case always gets called.

Comment: Seems to work for me... See [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-3myujc)